# Hosting website on personal laptop with offloaded storage and distribution

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I am concerned about the costs of running an EC2 instance and not happy with i/o speeds and expensive pricing . Instead I am thinking of using my laptop for the web application . To give you an idea about the app (  It is a user-generated site with video uploads and profiles . I`ll be using php mysql with memcached )

My PC : Windows 8 (can be changed to Ubuntu or any linux distro) , 4GB RAM , AMD A8 , (512 MB + 2gb ) video memory .

Workflow :

User visits the website and uploads a video . Using a file processing service , the file is uploaded to my S3 store . It is then transcoded using AWS transcoder and the URLs for playing are stored back to my database on the laptop . Amazon cloudfront is used as CDN .
I can free up any amount of spcae required for mysql (in TB range) if required , although seems unnecessary given how it will only be text .

Should I be worried about my upload speeds ?They are pathetic at 512 kbps on a good day . But , if I have offloaded the heavy duty work of video upload and transcoding , the only thing that remains to be served is text and I can find ways to minimize their impact for every user .I can sacrifice and not run any other major applications while the website is up .

I plan to use a lot of memcached queries and ec2 for same amount of storage and memory are very expensive to me (the main reason behind this complicated decision ) . Is there any minor or important link I`m missing ?

What are the pros Pros/cons of hosting php/mysql website on personal home laptop while offloading with storage to S3 and distribution offloaded to CDN?

Comment: OH. Goody... you want to run a youtube clone on a home connection... if you're not happy with EC2's i/o speed, you're going to be suicidally miserable dealing with cable/dsl upload speeds.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Or a real question at all.

Comment: @MarcB upload speed shouldn`t matter right? as I`m NOT hosting the videos ..

Comment: Oh Goody.... you want to open up your home laptop to every hacker on the planet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no reliability in your design - there are so many things that could fail - the battery, the hard disk, chipset due to heating, the home internet, the laptop itself going out of order, spilled soda/coffee, power cut, an ubuntu upgrade gone awry/ a windows virus, hackers targeting your laptop, a cat shutting the lid off...

Problem is, there are too many uncontrolled variables, and thus there is a much much greater probability of things breaking at your home then in a controlled environment like aws. Identification of Points of Failures/breach will be a nightmare as well.

The fact that there is no redundancy makes things worse; each of the above things that could fail will bring you down for days.

I am not sure about the cost of the laptop and that of your time, but be assured, if you truly expect that much amount of load, get yourself some server space.

Comment: Thank you for putting the sense back in me . I TOTALLY forgot about those variables . It was probably wishful thinking on my part :\